# Checking a string for a dot

Tags: perl

I'm having a hard time checking if a specific column from a csv file contains a dot or not.

The idea behind it is that i have to combine two columns which are first names of persons and last names of persons. but in some cases there are no first or last names in the columns.

Why do I need to know if their are dots or not? Because the first names are all shortened versions of their full names.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete source code example of what you tried yet ?

Comment: I've tried nothing i'm not a complete wizzkid on perl and the the google search i've got on this is next to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of perl's strengths is its regular expression engine. It's easy enough to use a regex to check for the presence of a dot, though a bit overkill. For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use 5.0100;

my $dotstring = "foo.bar";
my $nondotstring = "foodotbar";

foreach ( $dotstring, $nondotstring ) {
  if ( $_ =~ /\./ ) {
    say "There's a dot in $_";
  }
  else {
    say "There's no dot in $_";
  }
}
```

That's just a generic example, you'll need to fit it into the CSV parsing yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) to check for a substring within a string. It will return the position of the first match (starting from 0) or -1 if no match is found:

```
print index '.abc', '.';    # 0
print index 'abc.def', '.'; # 3
print index 'abc', '.';     # -1

if (index ($string, '.') >= 0) {
    # Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Text::CSV::Slurp to read your file then iterate over the rows of the result to see if the name column contains a dot.

```
my $data = Text::CSV::Slurp->load( file => ... )
for my $record (@$data) {
    if ($record->{Naam} =~ /\./) {
        ### Handle case here...
        ...
    }
}
```